# Singleton & Inheritance C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, singleton

First i'll just state that I'm using singletons that won't actually be around throughout the entire app life time. It's more a way of encapsulating what is going on from the user.

I have several GameStates, eg InGame or MainMenu, and these have some quite similar function calls so I thought to use inheritence to stop copy / pasting. The following code is what I have, but it does not work as I intend. Here it is:

BaseState.cs

```
abstract class BaseState
{
    protected static BaseState mHandle = null;

    protected static BaseState Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return mHandle;
        }
        set
        {
            mHandle = value;
        }
    }

    public static GameState UpdateState(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GameState g = GameState.MainMenu;

        try
        {
            Handle.Update(gameTime);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return g;
    }

    public static void DrawState(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        Handle.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
    }

    public static void Release()
    {
        mHandle = null;
    }

    protected abstract GameState Update(GameTime gameTime);
    protected abstract void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch);
}
```

InGame.cs

```
class InGame : BaseState
{
    private InGame()
    {

    }

    protected static new BaseState Handle
    {
        get
        {
            if (mHandle == null)
            {
                mHandle = new InGame();
            }

            return mHandle;
        }
        set
        {
            mHandle = value;
        }
    }

    protected override GameState Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        return GameState.Quit;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

    }
}
```

You can probably tell that I want to be able to use the `get` and `set` of `InGame` in the `BaseState` so I can simply call Handle.Update() and no matter if I called it from InGame or Menu or whatever it would know which code to use.

Obviously I need to brush up on my OO skills. But if anyone could suggest a way to get this to do what I would like it to, or to suggest a different way of going about it I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Where is GameState defined ? And you have to make a function virtual to be able to call it from a base class, but trigger derived class behavior (polymorphism). So your setter/getter should be virtual. Also, InGame.Update simply returns GameState.Quit, was that intended ?

Comment: GameState is a simple enum.
Yes it returns GameState.Quit intentionally for now
They can't be virtual as they are static, the two are opposites of each other I think? It gives compile errors at least; I tried the `new` keyword as it seemed like it's what I wanted and it compiled. Didn't do what I expect though.

Comment: I don't think you need a Singleton in your case, but plain and simple polymorphism. A singleton implies only one instance of a type can exist at any point, but in your case I believe multiple states can co-exist. Think about it, when you go from the game state to the menu state and back, you don't expect your game instance to be destroyed, but with a singleton you would have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve does not require a singleton, see below:

```
public abstract class BaseState
{
    public GameState UpdateState(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GameState g = GameState.MainMenu;

        try
        {
            g = Update(gameTime); // Update returns a new state
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return g;
    }

    protected abstract GameState Update(GameTime gameTime);
    protected abstract void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch);
}

public class InGame : BaseState
{
    public InGame()
    {

    }

    protected override GameState Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        return GameState.Quit;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        // Draw game
    }
}

public class InMenu : BaseState
{
    public InMenu()
    {

    }

    protected override GameState Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        return GameState.Pause;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        // Draw menu
    }
}

public void Foo()
{
    List<BaseState> states = new List<BaseState>();
    states.Add(new InGame());
    states.Add(new InMenu());

    // Calls InGame.Update(...)
    states[0].UpdateState(...);

    // Calls InMenu.Update(...)
    states[1].UpdateState(...);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is something like what I had originally, but it means that every state is persistent throughout the whole game when you don't really need the main menu in memory when you are in game. The idea of the static functions was to allocate and free up resources kind of automatically or at least hide it somewhat. I'll just move it into the main Game1 file and use plain old polymorphism.

Comment: If the menu takes any significant amount of memory, add a "ReleaseContent" method where it relinquish all memory hungry variables that can be reloaded from disk quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't override static members, so I think your approach here is wrong. You're better off using a factory or manager class (which could use a singleton to access the current instance, if you needed to) which will give you access to the current game state.

```
public class GameStateManager
{
    private static GameStateManager _instance = new GameStateManager();

    public static GameStateManager Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    public BaseState Current { get; private set; }

    public GameStateManager()
    {
         Current = new InGame();
    }

    public void ChangeState(GameState state, GameTime gameTime)
    {
         // change your current state here, I'm not really sure about your logic here
         Current.UpdateState(gameTime);

         switch(state)
         {
            case GameState.Menu:
              Current = new MainMenu();
            // etc.
            default:
               throw new NotImplementedException(string.Formatted("The state {0} is not implemented.", state));
         }
    }
}
```

You can access the singleton using `GameStateManager.Instance`.

Comment: The idea is very good. However I think there is a slight problem in this case: going from the game state to the pause state for example, deallocates the previous state. That is certainly not what you expect ! Maybe a state stack could be introduced ?

Also, his derived class Update method returns a new GameState so it would be state = Current.UpdateState(gameTime); and drop the GameState parameter to the ChangeState method.

Comment: Those are good points. I think a stack is a reasonable approach, so you could add and then remove a state (such as your pause example, where you have the Pause state pushed on top of the InGame state to draw the pause state over the in game state, and then remove it when the player unpauses). It seems, in that case, that a context or state argument should be passed into the `UpdateState` method, so the states can communicate (for example, the Pause state will want to signal to the InGame state that it should suspend animation).